# Remove pattern from array in Powershell

Tags: powershell

```
$testing = @("a.txt", "b.txt")
$testing | Select-String???
```

I would like the output to only contain `a`, `b`.
My real example is:

```
  $PackageNames = Get-ChildItem ("$DestinationPath\$ProjectName" + "_2105\" + $ProjectName) -Filter *.dtsx | Select-Object name -ExpandProperty name;
```

I need to use the content in this variable but without the extensions.

Comment: Are you really trying to remove file extensions? There's `FileInfo` class that has an attribute `BaseName`, which contains the file name without exension. If that's not your use case, [edit] the question and explain what kind of patterns you'd like to remove and keep. Can there be input such as `ab.txt`? Or `a.doc`? How should those be processed?

Comment: @vonPryz: Question edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working with files is easier, if you use `FileInfo` class' BaseName property. Like so,

```
$PackageNames = Get-ChildItem ("$DestinationPath\$ProjectName" + "_2105\" + $ProjectName) -Filter *.dtsx

# Process the results
foreach($pkg in $PackageNames) {
  $pkg.BaseName # Just prints the file name without extension
}
```

Comment: Downvoted by mistake, so I should not use expandproperty?

Comment: @David Do not use ExpandProperty in this case. It converts object properties to strings. After such conversion the file object properties are lost, so you can't use, say, `.FullName` or `.DirectoryName` properties.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$a|%{($_.tostring().split("."))[0]}
```

Iterate over the array, split by a dot and and get the first item.